# then(() => { don't send value in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, function

When i do this, after first `return` i don't have `user.uid` value:

```
const functions = require(`firebase-functions`);
exports.createNewUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user: { uid: string; }) => {

    const newUserWallet: UserWallet = new UserWallet(user.uid);
    const rootUserWallet = admin.database().ref(`/Users/UserWallet/${user.uid}`); //user.uid have value
    return rootUserWallet.set(newUserWallet).then(() => {
        const newUserSettings: UserSettings = new UserSettings(user.uid);
        const rootUserSettings = admin.database().ref(`/Users/UserSettings/${user.uid}`);   //user.uid is empty
        return rootUserSettings.set(newUserSettings);
    })
    })
```

I try send value like this:
`.then((user.uid) => {` or this: `.then(user.uid => {`, but i have error:

`Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '((value: void) => void | PromiseLike<void>) | null | undefined'.ts(2345)`

How can I sent this value there? It's Firebase Function triggered `OnCreate` new user. Write in TypeScript.

Comment: It's possible `uid` is gone from the object by the point you need it again. Try assigning it as a const before your return, and use that const instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do with the `{ uid: string; }` bit. I don't think that's the type of the `user` object.

In either case, why not put `user.uid` into a `const` and use it within your function from there? like this:

```js
exports.createNewUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
  const uid = user.uid;
  // replace all instances of 'user.uid' with just 'uid'?
})
```